# Codeigniter return variables from model to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, model, controller

I am in the process of creating an activation email for my registration process. I need to pass the variables containing the activation code and email address from my model back to my controller where I will send the email.

My registration form currently writes all signup data to the database and creates and activation code.

How can you pass the variables 'activation_code' and 'email' from my model back to my controller for use in my email.

**Model:**

```
... 
        $new_member_insert_data = array(
            'first_name' => $first_name,
            'last_name' => $last_name,
            'email_address' => $email,
            'password' => hashPassword($salt, $password, $hash),
            'activation_code' => activationCode($email, $hash.$salt),
            'hash' => $hash
        );

        $insert = $this->db->insert('members', $new_member_insert_data);
        return $insert;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
  $this->load->model('members_model');
                  if($this->members_model->create_member())//return variables here somehow
                    {

//get activation code + email variables
//send activation email
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'success');
                        redirect('home', 'location');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $viewdata['main_content'] = $category;
                        $this->load->view('includes/template', $viewdata);
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* simply return the array of values on success, or FALSE on failure:

```
$insert = $this->db->insert('members', $new_member_insert_data);
if ($insert) {
    return $new_member_insert_data; // Same data
}
else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

...but it doesn't really make sense, as you *must* be passing *something* to the model's method in order for it to be useful (or have access to some of these values beforehand, your given code is incomplete). Also, it can be confusing returning different data types and usually a bad idea.

Despite not having access to your full code here, I think the safest and most accurate way may be running another query after the `INSERT` runs. For instance, looking up the user by `email_address` (assuming it's supposed to be unique).

Comment: I followed your advice and ran a second function looking up the user by email address and getting the activation code. Thanks